# Protobuf: Can I parse special message format?

Tags: protocol-buffers, codec

I read information about Protobuf and understand that is a method of serializing **structured data**.

Now, I need to write codecs for [MSRP][1] protocol. MSRP is a text-based, connection-oriented protocol for exchanging arbitrary (binary) MIME [8] content, especially instant messages. There we have this special format of message:

```
MSRP dkei38sd SEND
Message-ID: 4564dpWd
Byte-Range: 1-*/8
Content-Type: text/plain

abcd
-------dkei38sd+
```

I don't understand, can we present this message format to the proto models?
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4975

Answer (score 1):

No, protocol buffers only handles its own three formats: protobuf binary, legacy protobuf text format and JSON format.

There is no support for parsing arbitrary data formats.